# How can we achieve NTLM authentication using Jmeter Automation

Tags: jmeter, ntlm

I was previously used Visual studio web test for automation. Now we have moved to **Jmeter**. We are trying to solve **NTLM** Authentication issues here but are unable to find out where to pass Credentials. The parameters below are required for file authentication in VS webtest:

1. CredentialUserName="CredentialUserName"
2. CredentialPassword="CredentialPassword"
3. PreAuthenticate="True"

I have found some helpful links and understand how NTLM works but am unable to find out how to use them in Jmeter.

I have found some useful links but am unable to get any information how to use NTLM in Jmeter.

[hc.apache.org](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

[apache.http.auth.NTCredentials](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) which deals with Basic, NTML and Kerberos authentication types, just add it to your Test Plan and provide username, password and domain there, JMeter will automatically build the relevant [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) and add it to your request(s).

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information.